# Spring Data JPA - find first by enum and order by date

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

The goal is to retrieve the last entity for a given UAI (enum). Not sure what is the best way to do it in Spring Data JPA, here is what I tried (not working)

My entity

```
public class AdmisHistory {
    // stuffs (id etc..)

    private Date jobExecutionDate;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UAI uai;

   // getters / setters
}
```

My JPA repository:

```
public interface AdmisHistoryRepository extends CrudRepository<AdmisHistory, Long> {
   public AdmisHistory findFirstByOrderByUaiByJobExecutionDateDesc(UAI uai);
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property byJobExecutionDate found for type UAI! Traversed path: AdmisHistory.uai.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want match by uai and get latest record

Try this:

```
public interface AdmisHistoryRepository extends CrudRepository<AdmisHistory, Long> {
   public AdmisHistory findTopByUaiOrderByJobExecutionDateDesc(UAI uai);
}
```